# Trailing slash not added with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, trailing-slash

I have the following .htaccess setup:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I want to achieve:

1. Redirect from http to https
2. Redirect from the non-www to www
3. Add trailing slash

The first two points are ok, the redirects are working as expected, but the third one doesn't.

How can I adapt the existing rules in order to add the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

You may use these rules in your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# add a trailing slash to non-files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing the updated rules.

Comment: Implemented the new rules as suggested and tried the links with a new browser, but it doesn't seem to work. Still no trailing slash added.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't paste the URL here.

Comment: Ok, then the URL is like this: https://www.example.com/articles/the-title-of-the-article-758

Comment: This is new since you never told about any 404? What URL are you entering in browser that causes 404? Also update your question with your full .htaccess?

Comment: I get a 404 when I add the URL without the trailing slash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166558/discussion-between-anubhava-and-cosmin).